# Is my older desktop capable of upgrading?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming

Good morning all, I've got a HP Pavilion I bought from my brother some years ago ;it was a work desktop prior. He had a shop replace the factory graphics card (NVIDIA GEFORCE 9500 GS) with a 1gb GEFORCE gt 710(MSI) because the port or something fried, which cost him about $300 at the time so I helped him recover some cost by purchasing it before buying a prebuild for himself. He had used it for games such as team fortress 2, Fallout 3, new Vegas, and maybe even Skyrim. however I played payday 2 effortlessly, and it ran War Thunder easily. It also has 4gb of RAM.

I basically just want this budget gamer to run DayZ without too much trouble while I save for a decent rig. Willing to spend another $100-$200 on this one if it's possible.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Wow that GT 710 was a massive scam. Even if it was during the GPU shortages

Comment: Your best upgrades are either RAM or SATA SSD.  If your computer has SATA  hard drive then upgrading to an SSD will definitely help but I worry that 4gb of RAM won't be enough.  1tb samsung 860 evo or 870 evo $120, but if you catch the sale price 2tb on amazon was recently on sale for $120.  Maybe you can find 4gb of RAM for the 80 remaining in your 200 budget.